# How to troubleshoot tsconfig file

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I have a large tsconfig file, and the compiler option's paths keep failing because of an error somewhere.
I do not know what line the error is at, and running yarn build doesn't provide any useful information.

Is there a way to find out where I am making a mistake in the tsconfig file?
I would like a solution that at least tells me what row the issue is at, instead of the whole file just failing to be processed and having to comment/uncomment each line one by one.